# Git pull crashes website

Tags: git, github, drupal, drupal-7, bitbucket

I had to overwrite my site from backup. Thing is my backup is behind GIT couple of commits.(deleted view, finishing touches on features, and a lot more). When I do git pull --all and pull all changes from GIT(which is ahead couple of commits) my site crashes. I assume its because those changes are written into database. Is there a way to avoid site crashing, so when I pull changes from GIT everything loads normally?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what changes git pull does. Tool (GIT) is not important here...more important is what changes are made in meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. Try adding more information like error messages.

With the info you gave us, it sounds like there's a bug in one of those git commits that is breaking your site. Starting from the working commit, pick one commit at a time to find which commit contains the bug. When you find it, either skip that commit or fix the bug.

You can use [git bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) to help you do this.

Comment: git bisect helped. same with git reset --hard number. i was able to skip broken commit and have minimal damage.